# Tailwind class not working after setting even though tailwind removes default css setting

Tags: html, css, node.js, tailwind-css

i installed with this npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@lates

created a script command "build-css": "tailwindcss build src/styles.css -o public/styles.css" in package.json

then ran the npm run build-css which creates a styles.css file in the public. I linked the HTML file in the public to the created styles.css file.

Now the page displays without the default CSS style which means that tailwind is active but I cant use tailwinds custom classes from the HTML

I have used both settings on styles.css below but still doesn't work[image]

Comment: What framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your CSS file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

this is the approach mentioned in documentation